# Android file create

Tags: android, json, oncreate

I just started to learn developping android and I have a (probably) basic questions, but I didn't find anything clear.

I'm trying to store data in a JSON file, well, I've understood the logic to store it, my way is:

```
public boolean writeFileJson(JSONObject jobj) {
    try {


        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fOut.write(jobj.toString().getBytes());
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

But my problem is to read, and concretely for the first time, because the way I do it is:

```
public String readFileJson() {

        int c;
        String temp = "";
        try {

            FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);
            while ((c = fin.read()) != -1) {
                temp = temp + Character.toString((char) c);
            }

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file read", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e2) {

        }
        return temp;
    }
```

So wen I read it for the first time and I want to acces to a parameter of my JSON is obvious that any JSON Object already exist in the file.

So I try to save a first JSON Object with my parameters in onCreate() method and save it in the file,  but wen I run the app, and I stop it, it returns again to execute onCreate() and deletes all data stored during the run time.

So my question is: There is any way to init only for one time the parameters of the JSON file to could access for the first time unlike it's empty???

I hope that I'd explained well!!

Thanxxxx!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own flag boolean and check when you start.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't understand well why you can use a flag if the flag is set to init value in onCreate(), but I've tried a basic method: check each time if the json file is null. But it's like so basic no? Is there any ther way, or trying to understand how to use flags without reset their values?

```
 msgjson = readFileJson();

                if(msgjson == "") {
                    json.put("ARRAY", jsonArray);
                }else{
                    json = new JSONObject(msgjson);
                }
```

Thanx!!